# Type: ParseError Message: syntax error, unexpected '?>'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to input some data into database with CRUD. Yesterday before i modified the code, it was normal, but after adding some code, it appears like this

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected '?>'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\reminder_pkb\application\views\Tambah_agenda.php

Line Number: 143

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\reminder_pkb\application\controllers\Data.php
Line: 21
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\reminder_pkb\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

[and here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpCG4.png)

Comment: Can you post the portion of `Data.php` line 21?

Comment: Edit your question and post your code there, dont post images, it makes it a lot harder to check code.

Comment: On line 143 of the posted image there is an empty echo inside the php tags. `<?php echo ?>`. That seems like an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 143 says

```
<?php echo ?>
```

This is a syntax error. It's missing some variable containing the url fragment corresponding to your site.